# How to change text of table row on click using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have written a code in which at the beginning when the page loads, a plus sign appears in column 1 along with some text. When the user clicks on that column( with a + sign), the second column in that row expands. At this point, I want <+> sign should 
 change to <->. The rest of the text in that column should remain same.
Similarly when the user again click on that first column, the second column collapses, and again I want the - sign to change to + sign.

The code for collapse/expansion is working fine. But I'm unable to convert the signs from + to - and vice versa.

Can someone please help me.

Below is the code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=en_US">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
tr.even {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
tr.odd {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.xhide
{
}

</style>



    </head>
    <!-- comments only
    -->
    <body>
<hr>

<table>
      <tbody>
    <tr>
          <td width="5%"></td>
          <td><table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
              <thead>
              <tr style="font-size:16px; background-color:lightgray;">
                  <th><a name="table">&nbsp;</a>Column1</th>
                  <th>Column2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr  class="odd">
                  <td id = "x"><span id="expand"><b style="font-size:30px">+</b></span> Country</td>
                  <td>
                       <p>India</p>
                       <p class = "xhide" >Europe</p>
                      <p class = "xhide" >Asia</p>
                      <p class = "xhide" >Russia</p>
                 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr  class="odd">
                  <td id = "x"><span id="expand"><b style="font-size:30px">+</b></span> Country</td>
                  <td>
                       <p>India</p>
                       <p class = "xhide" >Europe</p>
                      <p class = "xhide" >Asia</p>
                      <p class = "xhide" >Russia</p>
                 </td>
                </tr>

                 </tbody>
            </table></td>
          <td width="5%"></td>
        </tr>

  </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".xhide").hide();

    $("#expand").click(function(){
        $(".xhide").toggle(300);        
        if($("#expand").html() == "-"){
            $("#expand").html("+");
        }
        else{
            $("#expand").html("-");
        };
        $("#expand").css("style" , "font-size:30px");
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** implemented the comments

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".xhide").hide();
    $(".expand").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('expanded')) this.innerHTML= this.innerHTML.replace('-','+');
        else this.innerHTML= this.innerHTML.replace('+','-');
        $(this).parent('tr').find(".xhide").toggle(500);
        $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
    });
});
```

```css
tr.even {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
tr.odd {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
.expand b{
    font-size:30px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tbody>
    <tr>
          <td width="5%"></td>
          <td><table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
              <thead>
              <tr style="font-size:16px; background-color:lightgray;">
                  <th><a name="table">&nbsp;</a>Column1</th>
                  <th>Column2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr  class="odd">
                  <td class = "expand"><b>+</b> Country</td>
                  <td>
                       <p>India</p>
                       <p class = "xhide" >Europe</p>
                      <p class = "xhide" >Asia</p>
                      <p class = "xhide" >Russia</p>
                 </td>
                </tr><tr  class="odd">
                  <td class = "expand"><b>+</b> Country</td>
                  <td>
                       <p>India</p>
                       <p class = "xhide" >Europe</p>
                      <p class = "xhide" >Asia</p>
                      <p class = "xhide" >Russia</p>
                 </td>
                </tr> </tbody>
            </table></td>
          <td width="5%"></td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes , I want to use this more than once. Is there some generic way in which this can be done ? Please help.

Comment: Yes use a class e.g. expand. And also think about reverting the - to a +. So it might be good to add an extra class e.g. expanded. Also the `$(".xhide").toggle(500);` needs to be changed to only show hide those in the same tr e.g. `$(this).parent().children(".xhide").toggle(500);`

Comment: Ok Domenik, I will wait for your answer.

Comment: I tried to make a new class as suggested by you, but could not get it to work

Comment: @DeepikaBansal I made an example with two rows, that work independently from each other.

Comment: Hi Domenik, Thanks, one last question . I added this alongwith the + sign :  <td class = "expand"><b style="font-size:30px">+</b> Country</td>
                  <td>

Comment: When i now click on + , it size again becomes small. Can you please tell me how to keep the sign of +/- same as size of initially + . I tried using css property on this.textcontent but it does not seem to work

Comment: Fixed it. Needed to move the font size to the css part. I also fixed that when you would have clicked on the + itself it might have had some trouble.

Comment: @DeepikaBansal if you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as solved. thx and glad I could help.

Comment: one last thing, is there some link where I can check the usage of 'expanded' ?  referring to : hasClass ('expanded')

Comment: I don't quite understand you question. Do you mean a counter how often it got opened/closed?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".xhide").hide();

    $("tr.odd").click(function(){
        $(this).find(".xhide").toggle(500);
        var currentRow = $(this).find("#expand");
        if(currentRow.hasClass('expanded')){
         currentRow.html("+");
        }
        else{
         currentRow.html("-");
        }
        currentRow.toggleClass('expanded');
    });
});
```

```css
tr.even {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
tr.odd {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.xhide
{
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=en_US">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <!-- comments only
    -->
    <body>
<hr>

<table>
      <tbody>
    <tr>
          <td width="5%"></td>
          <td><table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
              <thead>
              <tr style="font-size:16px; background-color:lightgray;">
                  <th><a name="table">&nbsp;</a>Column1</th>
                  <th>Column2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr  class="odd">
                  <td id = "x"><span id="expand">+</span> Country</td>
                  <td>
                       <p>India</p>
                       <p visibility:hidden;  class = "xhide" >Europe</p>
                      <p class = "xhide" >Asia</p>
                      <p class = "xhide" >Russia</p>
                 </td>
                </tr>
              <tr  class="odd">
                  <td id = "x"><span id="expand">+</span> Country</td>
                  <td>
                       <p>India</p>
                       <p visibility:hidden;  class = "xhide" >Europe</p>
                      <p class = "xhide" >Asia</p>
                      <p class = "xhide" >Russia</p>
                 </td>
                </tr>                
                </tbody>
            </table></td>
          <td width="5%"></td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I used your solution. It worked but there is one more problem. I enhanced my solution for multiple rows, and now when i click on first row + sign, second row also expands with it. Another issue is that if I click on second row, it does not expand. Can you please have a look. I have updated my code in the original question place.

Comment: Yes I will look to it, you first example is only one row :)

Comment: Thanks mbadeveloper, But Domenik below has solved the multiple row problem (he has attached his code) , now one problem remains of size of +/- which I have explained below. Can you please help ?

Comment: @DeepikaBansal You checked my solution is working for both rows. Just I changed it

Comment: - does not change back to +

Comment: Now is working. Sorry I forget to remove some testing code.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution by Domenik is working fine :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".xhide").hide();
    $(".expand").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('expanded')) this.innerHTML= this.innerHTML.replace('-','+');
        else this.innerHTML= this.innerHTML.replace('+','-');
        $(this).parent('tr').find(".xhide").toggle(500);
        $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
    });
});
```

```css
tr.even {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
tr.odd {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
.expand b{
    font-size:30px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tbody>
    <tr>
          <td width="5%"></td>
          <td><table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
              <thead>
              <tr style="font-size:16px; background-color:lightgray;">
                  <th><a name="table">&nbsp;</a>Column1</th>
                  <th>Column2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr  class="odd">
                  <td class = "expand"><b>+</b> Country</td>
                  <td>
                       <p>India</p>
                       <p class = "xhide" >Europe</p>
                      <p class = "xhide" >Asia</p>
                      <p class = "xhide" >Russia</p>
                 </td>
                </tr><tr  class="odd">
                  <td class = "expand"><b>+</b> Country</td>
                  <td>
                       <p>India</p>
                       <p class = "xhide" >Europe</p>
                      <p class = "xhide" >Asia</p>
                      <p class = "xhide" >Russia</p>
                 </td>
                </tr> </tbody>
            </table></td>
          <td width="5%"></td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```